# Float to string (removing trailing zeros)

Tags: ios

Can anyone help me with converting float to string?

if I use `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", f]` I will get something like:
1.0300000
1.0000000
1.0471000

if I use [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", f] I will get rounded values like:
1.03
1.00
1.05

but I need
1.03
1
1.0471

please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code for your project

```
- (NSString *) floatToString:(float) val {
    NSString *ret = [NSString stringWithFormat:@\"%.5f\", val];
    unichar c = [ret characterAtIndex:[ret length] - 1];
    while (c == 48 || c == 46) { // 0 or .
        ret = [ret substringToIndex:[ret length] - 1];
        c = [ret characterAtIndex:[ret length] - 1];
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Won't work if the current locale uses anything else that a '.' for a decimal separator.

Answer (score 5):

Use `NSNumberFormatter` instead and set maximumFractionDigits.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfNumberFormatting10_4.html

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSNumberFormatter/setMaximumFractionDigits:

Comment: Yes, it works fir me. As far as i know, we were formatting numbers to strings, not parsing strings.